# insert an element into container without changing its original adress in C++

Tags: c++, testing, containers, push, memory-address

I have 2 classes. The class Covid has a list of Deviant.
I need to add an Deviant to the list .

```
class Deviant : public Individu{
    public:
        Deviant();
        Deviant(const Personne& );
        Deviant(const Personne&, const std::string& );
        ~Deviant();
        const std::string& getObs() const;
        void setObs(const std::string&);
    std::vector<Personne> p;
    std::string obs;

};
class Covid{
    public:
        Covid();
        ~Covid();
        void push(const Deviant&);
        const Deviant& top() const;
    std::list<Deviant > d;
};
```

I need to implement methods push() that pushes a Deviant into list d and top() that returns the first element in the list d.
I need to pass this test

```
TEST_CASE("COVID") {
  Deviant  zz[] = { Deviant(Personne("bruno") , "19980930"), 
                    Deviant(Personne("alexis"), "20160930"), 
                    Deviant(Personne("loic")  , "19990930"), 
                    Deviant(Personne("jeremy"), "20210930") 
                   };

  Covid c;
  for (int i=0; i< 4; ++i)
     c.push(zz[i]);
  std::cout << c.top().getObs() << std::endl;
  std::cout << zz[3].getObs() << std::endl;
   CHECK(&c.top() == &zz[3]);
   /*c.pop();
   CHECK(&c.top() == &zz[1]);
   c.pop();
   CHECK(&c.top() == &zz[2]);
   c.pop();
   CHECK(&c.top() == &zz[0]);*/
}
```

but the first check does pass

```
tests.cpp:225: FAILED:
  CHECK( &c.top() == &zz[3] )
with expansion:
  0x000055bded197be0 == 0x00007fffad1896a8
```

what is the best container to store objects without changing their original addresses ?

Comment: `what is the best container to store objects without changing their original addresses ?` Its impossible to do that. You have to store pointers to get this result.

Comment: `emplace_back` inserts directly into STL containers like std::list. The objects space is reserved directly and its assembled in place. So its address does not change, but it also does not exist outside the container

Comment: Why would you have such a need, store a smart pointer to the object in the container. Sounds like an XY problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test will always fail, because `std::list` makes a *copy* of whatever is pushed into it.  You are testing the *copy*'s address against the *original*'s address, which will never match. The only way to push an object into a container without copying/moving it is to push a *pointer* to the object instead. IOW, use `std::list<Deviant*>` and `c.push(&zz[i]);`, and then adjust  `top()` and your tests accordingly, eg:

```
class Covid{
    public:
        Covid();
        ~Covid();
        void push(Deviant*);
        const Deviant* top() const;
    std::list<Deviant*> d;
};
```

```
TEST_CASE("COVID") {
  Deviant  zz[] = { Deviant(Personne("bruno") , "19980930"), 
                    Deviant(Personne("alexis"), "20160930"), 
                    Deviant(Personne("loic")  , "19990930"), 
                    Deviant(Personne("jeremy"), "20210930") 
                   };

  Covid c;
  for (int i=0; i< 4; ++i)
     c.push(&zz[i]);
  std::cout << c.top()->getObs() << std::endl;
  std::cout << zz[3].getObs() << std::endl;
   CHECK(c.top() == &zz[3]);
   /*c.pop();
   CHECK(c.top() == &zz[1]);
   c.pop();
   CHECK(c.top() == &zz[2]);
   c.pop();
   CHECK(c.top() == &zz[0]);*/
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that too but it's an exam so I thought it might be a way to do it.

Comment: @ikramzouaoui There is no way to make your original code work the way you are trying to. I'm guessing you have misunderstood what the exam is asking for.

Comment: I think soo. Thank you for your help